# Express does not return valid response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

i am trying to use mongodb to get some data for our analytics page, there's alot of data that's processing but for some reason the express returns empty array as response even when i use console log i see the data on terminal.

This is my endpoint

```
import Analytics from '../classes/Analytics';
import { Router } from 'express';
import role from '../middleware/role';

const router = Router();

router.use(role('admin'));


router.get('/analytics/weekly', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await Analytics.getWeekly();

        return res.status(200).send({ data });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Something went wrong, please try again later!' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is where all the magic happens for data variable

```
class Analytics {
    static async getWeekly() {
        // ignore this one day difference thing
        const startDate = moment().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('week').format();
        const endDate = moment().subtract(1, 'days').endOf('week').format();

        try {
            const orders = await Order.find(
                {
                    sent_at: {
                        $gte: startDate,
                        $lte: endDate,
                    },
                },
                { user: 1, created_at: 1, sent_at: 1 }
            );

            let counter = [];

            for await (const item of orders) {
                const date = moment(item.sent_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH');

                if (!counter[date]) counter[date] = [];

                if (!counter[date][item.user.username]) counter[date][item.user.username] = 0;

                counter[date][item.user.username] += 1;
            }

            return counter;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

The point of the static method above is to fetch all orders and count how many times which user has handled the order.

Now when i console.log the data from the router endpoint i see the data on console perfectly just how i wanted it to be

```
 '2021-07-03 22': [
    Johnson: 10,
    Mikaels: 15,
    Vasquez: 24,
    Blaskovich: 3
  ],
  '2021-07-03 23': [
    Johnson: 2,
    Vasquez: 12,
    Mikaels: 15,
    Blaskovich: 5
  ]
```

The problem is when i make a request to my endpoint it returns an empty array `[]`. What am i missing here?

Comment: @LonnieBest how come that happen if i am using console log on the endpoint and it shows data

Comment: So after await console.log() shows data but in front end you do not get it?

Comment: @TusharShahi in http response more precisely

Comment: @LonnieBest its running on my local machine and i am making get request to /analytics/weekly

Comment: Probably add more code from your routes file. Everything looks good though.

Comment: @TusharShahi added the imports there's nothing else besides that

Comment: Probably not the cause, but it's worthless to have the `await` in `for await (const item of orders)` since `orders` is a normal array.  Remove that `await`.

Comment: Also, in your `catch`, add `throw err` so that you are not eating the error, but are propagating it back to the caller.

Comment: @jfriend00 was just trying to put await before everything because i was losing my mind

Comment: Never put `await` somewhere unless you know exactly why it's there and you know that you're awaiting a promise.  Code guessing for something you don't really understand does not lead to good code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if (!counter[date]) counter[date] = [];
```

to this:

```
if (!counter[date]) counter[date] = {};
```

And this:

```
let counter = [];
```

to this:

```
let counter = {};
```

Your code here:

```
if (!counter[date][item.user.username]) counter[date][item.user.username] = 0;
```

Is adding a property to an array, not adding an array element.  And `JSON.stringify()` ignores properties on an array.  It only serializes actual array elements so when you try to send the JSON version of the array, it always appears empty.

So, when you call `res.status(200).send({ data });`, the `.send()` method serializes your object which contains a bunch of arrays that have no actual array elements, only properties.

By changing the arrays to be objects, then `JSON.stringify()` will serialize all those properties.  Arrays and Objects have many things in common, but they are not the same.  You should use the appropriate type for your situation.

---

In addition, change this:

```
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

to this:

```
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
```

So that you are properly propagating errors back to the caller.  Otherwise, you're just eating the error and returning `undefined`, both of which will cause problems for the caller.

Comment: Had to change `counter = {}` as well, anything else works just fine, thanks alot 